# For a Sum-of-Squares cost functions J(x) is it true that J(x)-j* is also SOS?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, fields, sums-of-squares

For polynomial optimization problems the sum-of-squares theory and Lasserre relaxation hierarchy provides a theoretically handy way of getting the solution. There are also results saying that finite relaxation is enough for global convergence.

My question is related to the unconstrained optimization of polynomials of the following form
$$
J(x) = \sum_{k=1}^N q^2_k(x)
$$
where $q_i(x)$ are arbitrary polynomials (they do have structure in my particular case, but I hope that wont be needed to get an answer).

Since $J(x)$ is sum of squares, it is non-negative. Let its minimum value be
$$
j^* = \min_{x}J(x)
$$

I know that there are general polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x)-p^*$ is not sum-of-squares. The questions is whether the assumption that $P(x)$ is sum-of-squares helps this situation or not.

Is $J(x)-j^*$ is also a sum of squares polynomial? If not, do we have a counterexample?

Any pointers towards relevant literature is also appreciated, as searching "is sum-of-squares" is useless for such specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motzkin polynomial in the homogeneous form, i.e. $f(x):=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^4x_2^2 + x_1^2x_2^4 − 3x_1^2x_2^2x_3^2 + x_3^6$ becomes an SOS if you add  $\frac{3}{16}x_1^6$ to it. $3/16$ is an upper bound on minimum such value (a better bound is $(3/4)^6$), as can be checked e.g. by using a nice [Macaulay2 package](http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~hpeyrl/Projects/SOS/rational_sos.php) by H.Peyrl. Thus $P(x):=f(1,x_2,x_3)+\frac{3}{16}$ is a counterexample.

Below is the Macaulay code to run to find an appriximation to the minimal $a$ so that $f(1,y,z)+a$ is SOS (after installing that package), and its output, in the format ({list of squares},{list of positive coefficients for them},{value of a})

```
 S = QQ[z,y,a];
 f = y^2 + y^4 + z^6 - 3*y^2*z^2 + a;
 (g,d,aval)=getSOS (f,{a},a)

    2   2 2   17    15 3       3          9  51   1    11    3     3
 ({z  - -y  - --, - --z  + z, z , 1, y}, {-, --, ---, ----, --}, {--})
        3     60    17                    4  40  136  1600  20    16
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? If memory servers me well, the Motzkin polynomial is a rather special positive polynomial that will not become SOS no matter how big of a positive number you add to it.

Comment: Yes, I was right. This is mentioned for example here, page 67, Example 4.4.3: http://math.ucsd.edu/~njw/PHD/njwphdthesis.pdf

Comment: It is mentioned that $f^*_{SOS} = -\infty$ for the Motzkin polynomial.

Comment: oops, sorry, my bad. Now I recall seeing this $f^*_{SOS}=-\infty$ somewhere. Probably some other famous example is not as crazy...

Comment: it works for a different dehomogenesation, cf. my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, you deserve the credit. It might be that the special structure of my $q_k$ polynomials helps but that is way too complex to be treated exactly. If you have knowledge about literature that contains sufficient conditions for positive polynomials $P(x)$, such that $P-p^*$ is SOS, I would appreciate those pointers as well.

Comment: Nonlinear least squares problems have this kind of structure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares

Comment: I could not find a statement about this on the wikipedia page. Can you give a paper or book reference, where it is stated and proved, that non-linear least squares cost functions will always adopt an SOS decomposition?

Comment: oh, I just meant to say that in nonlinear least squares the structure of the problem is similar to yours. (And nonlinear least squares have received a lot of attention...)